Ratio between columns with nan values. How to choose the column, for each row, without nan values in pandas?
I have the following DF:
z = pd.DataFrame({2016:[4.0,np.nan,6.0,7.0,np.nan],2017:[np.nan,0,5.0,0,np.nan],2018:[4.0,3,np.nan,3,1.0],2019:[2.0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3.4],'ratio':''})
I need a column named 'ratio' to store the ratio between the first year (without nan values) and last year (without nan values) for each row.
For example, for first row it would be 2016/2019, for the second, 2017/2018, for the third, 2016/2017 and so on.
I couldn't figure out how to solve this....

Code
If you need vectorisation operations, use code below:
tmp = df.filter(regex=r"^\d+$").bfill(axis=1).ffill(axis=1)
df["ratio"] = tmp.iloc[:, 0] / tmp.iloc[:, -1]

z -> df
In your example, the variable in the data frame is z, but used df for the convenience of the viewer.

Try:
# filter only years
years = df.filter(regex=r"^\d+$")

df["ratio"] = years.apply(
    lambda row: row[row.first_valid_index()] / row[row[::-1].first_valid_index()],
    axis=1,
)

print(df)

Prints:
   2016  2017  2018  2019     ratio
0   4.0   NaN   4.0   2.0  2.000000
1   NaN   0.0   3.0   NaN  0.000000
2   6.0   5.0   NaN   NaN  1.200000
3   7.0   0.0   3.0   NaN  2.333333
4   NaN   NaN   1.0   3.4  0.294118


OR: Use .last_valid_index() (Thanks @BhanuTez)
df["ratio"] = years.apply(
    lambda row: row[row.first_valid_index()] / row[row.last_valid_index()],
    axis=1,
)


going by your logic it is better to use last_valid_index(). Instead of reversing the row

What is years = df.filter(regex=r"^\d+$") for?
